# PHP resize image keeping aspect ratio to exact size

Tags: php, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I need to manually find DPI of new image.

```
$input_width = 361;
$input_height = 413;

$input_dpi_x = 72;
$input_dpi_y = 72;

$output_width = 800;
$output_height = $input_height * $output_width / $input_width;

$output_dpi_x = ceil(($input_dpi_x / $input_width) * $output_width);
$output_dpi_y = ceil(($input_dpi_y / $input_height) * $output_y_res);

echo "Outpud_dpi_x = " . $output_dpi_x;
//Outpud_dpi_x = 160
```

Why when i resize image i get 802 instead of 800?

and i must use DPI dont ask why

Comment: I'd perform the multiplication before division to avoid loss of precision but with the numbers you're talking about, that's a pretty massive rounding error

Comment: can you show me exactly what you mean i am not a match person.

Comment: Your title is asking to keep aspect ratio of an image, but your question is about calculating DPI.  Is there a different way to phrase the issue so we can provide a solution?

Comment: What if you use `round()` instead  of `ceil()` ?

Comment: Is this for some kind of print format? I'm not aware of any image format that allows different dpi for height vs width, they should be the same... For onscreen images is dpi completely irrelevant, only # of pixels per side matter.

Comment: @jheddings just read the code not title

Comment: @JohnSmith - not usually the best way to solicit support from the community

Comment: Instead of `(A/B)*C` I meant `C*A/B` but that's not the issue in this case - it's too large to be a rounding issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is all in the math...  Let's just focus on the width for simplicity.

Pulling back the layers a little bit, start with scaling operations (reordered to help with loss of precision).  Here, I'm calculating the output DPI value and verifying the result by solving the original equation for `$output_width`.

```
$output_dpi_x = $output_width * $input_dpi_x / $input_width;  // 159.5567867...
$output_width = $output_dpi_x * $input_width / $input_dpi_x;  // 800
```

You can see with this non-corrected value for DPI, we arrive back at 800 for the width value.  When we round up to the next number (using the `ceil` operator), it changes the results.  By unwinding the math, we can see why you end up with 802px in the output:

```
$output_dpi_x = ceil($output_dpi_x);  // 160
$output_width = $output_dpi_x * $input_width / $input_dpi_x;  // 802.22222222...
```

Of course, images can't contain partial pixels, so your resized image is rounded down to 802px.

Comment: Ok sorry for the trouble people, the problem was that i used trim() function for the image after setting size that messed up the size, actually my formula was OK, i however written a better one already.

Imagick Extension